# Cannot edit perticular user's data using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii framework. I am doing update operation using yii framework. I have controller with name sitecontroller.php, model jobseekerprofile.php, view personal.php. I can't update data by form posting.

My controller is sitecontroller.php

```
<?php
class SiteController extends Controller
 {
 public function actionpersonal()
  {

    $user_id = trim($_GET['id']);
    $model = new jobseekerprofile();
    if(isset($_POST['jobseekerprofile']))
     {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['jobseekerprofile'];
        if($model->save())
           {
              $this->redirect(array('profile','user_id'=>$model->user_id));
           }   
    }

    $model=jobseekerprofile::model()->find(array(
                                         'select'=>'contact_no,address',"condition"=>"user_id=$user_id",
                                         'limit'=>1,));
    $this->render('personal',array('model' =>$model));
  }
}
```

?>

My view page personal.php

```
<div class="form">
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'login-form',
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true
),
 )); ?>

<?php
foreach(Yii::app()->user->getFlashes() as $key => $message) {
    echo '<div class="flash-' . $key . '">' . $message . "</div>\n";
}
 ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>
   <div class="row">
   <?php //echo $form->textField($model,'pp_status', array('value'=>'Open', 'readonly' => 'true')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Contact No'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'contact_no'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'contact_no'); ?>
</div>

 <div class="row">

    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Address'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'address'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'address'); ?>
</div>  

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

My model jobseekerprofile.php

```
<?php
```

class Jobseekerprofile extends CActiveRecord
    {
    public $contact_no;
    public $dob;
    public $gender;
    public $mstatus;
    public $address;
    public $user_id;

```
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
 {
return parent::model($className);
 }
public function tableName()
{
    return 'job_seeker_profile';
}
public function rules()
  {
    return array(
    array('contact_no,gender,dob,address,mstatus','required'),
    );
 }
```

}
  ?>

Anybody help me?

Comment: add action in your form and change controller function name actionpPrsonal

Comment: controller name-Sitecontroller.php,,my action name -personal,,my view file name -personal.php

Answer (score 0):

Because on each request you create new jobseekerprofile model, then this code will create new jobseekerprofile record each time you submit. Change your action into this:

```
public function actionpersonal()
{

$user_id = trim($_GET['id']);
$model=jobseekerprofile::model()->find(array(
                                     'select'=>'contact_no,address',"condition"=>"user_id=$user_id",
                                     'limit'=>1,));
if(isset($_POST['jobseekerprofile']))
 {
    $model->attributes=$_POST['jobseekerprofile'];
    if($model->save())
       {
          $this->redirect(array('profile','user_id'=>$model->user_id));
       }   
}


$this->render('personal',array('model' =>$model));
}
```

This should works.

Comment: Try set 'enableClientValidation' to false, remove 'enctype', and check $jobseekerprofile->errors. There might be problems on jobseekerprofile rules.

Comment: gender,dob,mstatus fields are required but not set. Set it before saving the model.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given the primary key of the user which you want to edit.
Try following

$model=jobseekerprofile::model()->findByPk($id);
$id is the primary key of the table. 
Then you can write following

```
if($model->save())
           {
              $this->redirect(array('profile','user_id'=>$model->user_id));
           }
```

if you only use $model->save() it will insert data, but not update.